# facebook api: does requesting publish_stream require confirmation from the user each time they login

Tags: php, facebook, api

When I add publish_stream in the scope for a facebook api login url like below it asks the user to confirm that my app can access the email/birthday etc and that I can publish on their behalf.

That's okay - but the second time they login it still asks them to confirm the second stage about permission to publish to their timeline. Is this normal like a security thing or is there a way around this?

(edit: the app shows up on the users facebook account with publish permissions)

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
array(
        'display'   => 'popup',
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://www.example.com/return.php',
        'scope' => 'user_birthday,email,publish_stream'
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is normal because the publish permission should not be asked at login but when the user wants to share something. Have a look at the official best practices [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/checklist/#avoidbacktoback).

Comment: Thanks - would up vote you too for the extra bit of info but rep on this account is a little low!